# How can I remove AutoNumeric formatting before submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autonumeric.js

I'm using the jQuery plugin [AutoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) but when I submit a form, I can't remove the formatting on the fields before `POST`.

I tried to use `$('input').autonumeric('destroy')` (and other methods) but it leaves the formatting on the text fields.

How can I `POST` the unformatted data to the server? How can I remove the formatting? Is there an attribute for it in the initial config, or somewhere else?

I don't want to send the serialized form data to the server (with AJAX). I want to submit the form with the unformatted data like a normal HTML action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wrote a better, somewhat more general hack for this in jQuery

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $('input').each(function(i){
        var self = $(this);
        try{
            var v = self.autoNumeric('get');
            self.autoNumeric('destroy');
            self.val(v);
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Not an autonumeric field: " + self.attr("name"));
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

This code cleans form w/ error handling on not autoNumeric values.

Comment: nice, but for a sec or two (while form is submitting) I see the unformatted value. It's just a cosmetic issue, but it's little annoying.

Comment: There is no need for this anymore, you can just use the following option now : `{ unformatOnSubmit : true }`

Answer (score 12):

With newer versions you can use the option:

```
unformatOnSubmit: true
```

Comment: Does not seem to work with ajax form submission, any alternatives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65885332/5668611 works with Ajax form submissions.

Answer (score 2):

Inside data callback you must call getString method like below:

```
        $("#form").autosave({
        callbacks: {
            data: function (options, $inputs, formData) {

                return $("#form").autoNumeric("getString");
            },
            trigger: {
                method: "interval",
                options: {
                    interval: 300000
                }
            },
            save: {
                method: "ajax",
                options: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Action',
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get` method.

> 'get' | returns un-formatted object via ".val()" or
>   ".text()" | $(selector).autoNumeric('get');

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clean(form) {
        form["my_field"].value = "15";
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="submit.php" onsubmit="clean(this)">
    <input type="text" name="my_field">
</form>
```

This will always submit `"15"`. Now get creative :)

---

Mirrored raw value:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input type="text" name="my_field_formatted" id="my_field_formatted">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_field" id="my_field_raw">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_field_formatted").change(function () {
        $("#my_field").val($("#my_field_formatted").autoNumeric("get"));
    });
</script>
```

The in `submit.php` ignore the value for `my_field_formatted` and use `my_field` instead.

Comment: get method returns the value of the input field. i need to submit the unformatted form. i don't want to get the unformatted value for a field.

Comment: Then `get` the value and submit that? I'm assuming you have some custom `onsubmit` handler in place, if not, make one, you'll need it.

Comment: so it's not possible to submit the unformatted data without ajax request?

Comment: Sure it is. You can modify the values of fields in your onsubmit handler. It wont be as nice and clean as AJAX but it's certainly doable.

Comment: if you can provide me this solution, i'll certainly accept your answer. :)

Comment: i've already implemented something like that, but i thought there's a cleaner solution... are you sure there's no other way?

Comment: AJAX could be a _clean_ solution. Another solution is that you mirror the value of the formatted field to a hidden field that contains just the value. The submit handler should ignore the formatted value and just look at the raw value, I'll update my answer.

Comment: i've answered the question above and i'll use this in my code

Answer (score 1):

You can always use php `str_replace` function

```
str_repalce(',','',$stringYouWantToFix);
```

it will remove all commas. you can cast the value to integer if necessary.

Comment: why php? (fyi i used java on server side for the app.) wrong solution, not an answer.

Comment: That's not matter. Java probably have methods with similar functionality. I see it as a solution because it will remove the formatting and that's want we want. why its important to do it client side?

Comment: because it's much cleaner in a multi-layered application. read i.e.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.classname").autoNumeric('init',{your_options});
$('form').submit(function(){
   var form=$(this);
   $('form').find('input.classname').each(function(){
       var self=$(this);
       var v = self.autoNumeric('get');
       // self.autoNumeric('destroy');
       self.val(v);
   });
});
```

**classname** is your input class that will init as autoNumeric
Sorry for bad English ^_^

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for integration which doesn't interfere with your client-side validation nor causes the flash of unformatted text before submission:

```
var input = $(selector);
var proxy = document.createElement('input');
proxy.type = 'text';
input.parent().prepend(proxy);
proxy = $(proxy);
proxy.autoNumeric('init', options);
proxy.autoNumeric('set', input.val())''
proxy.change(function () {
    input.val(proxy.autoNumeric('get'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **getArray** method (http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/#getArrayAnchor).

`$.post("myScript.php", $('#mainFormData').autoNumeric('getArray'));`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, seems like the cleanest way.
I know it's a pretty old thread but it's the first Google match, so i'll leave it here for future

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    $('.curr').each(function(){
        $(this).autoNumeric('update', {aSign: '', aDec: '.', aSep: ''});;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for AJAX Use Case**

> I believe this is better answer among all of those mentioned above, as the person who wrote the question is doing AJAX. So
> kindly upvote it, so that people find it easily. For non-ajax form submission, answer given by @jpaoletti is the right one.

```
// Get a reference to any one of the AutoNumeric element on the form to be submitted
var element = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#modifyQuantity');

// Unformat ALL elements belonging to the form that includes above element
// Note: Do not perform following in AJAX beforeSend event, it will not work
element.formUnformat();

$.ajax({
    url: "<url>",
    data : {
        ids : ids,
        orderType : $('#modifyOrderType').val(),
        
        // Directly use val() for all AutoNumeric fields (they will be unformatted now)
        quantity : $('#modifyQuantity').val(),
        price : $('#modifyPrice').val(),
        triggerPrice : $('#modifyTriggerPrice').val()
    }
})
.always(function(  ) {
    // When AJAX is finished, re-apply formatting    
    element.formReformat();     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`autoNumeric("getArray")` no longer works.

`unformatOnSubmit: true` does not seem to work when form is submitted with Ajax using serializeArray().

Instead use `formArrayFormatted` to get the equivalent serialised data of `form.serializeArray()`

Just get any AutoNumeric initialised element from the form and call the method. It will serialise the entire form including non-autonumeric inputs.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement("#anyElement").formArrayFormatted(),
)};
```