# JQuery currency formatting, but submit only the number

Tags: jquery, forms, currency, number-formatting

I found this plugin for jQuery where you can type a number (let's say "650") and the input field would automatically change it to €650,-.

But when I submit the form, the form value is "€650,-" (not very suprising).

What I want is the functionality that the plugin would change it back to "650" on submitting the form. The inputs should only accept whole euro's, so "650,40" is not permitted.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: what jquery plugin you used? there is usually an api from the plugin to get the actual value..

Comment: I saw this demo: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: I think this thread will help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815771/autonumeric-js-remove-formatting-before-submitting-form I will try this first

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used to answer this question:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $('input').each(function(i){
        var self = $(this);
        try{
            var v = self.autoNumeric('get');
            self.autoNumeric('destroy');
            self.val(v);
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Not an autonumeric field: " + self.attr("name"));
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Thanks to:

[autoNumeric.js remove formatting before submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815771/autonumeric-js-remove-formatting-before-submitting-form)

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit the `form` manually, for example if you have `form` like this...

```
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" id="autoNum"/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="onsubmit()"/>
</form>
<script>
 $(function()
 $("#autoNum").autoNumeric();
 });
  function onsubmit(){
    $("#autoNum").val($("#autoNum").autoNumeric("get"));
    document.f1.submit();
  }
</script>
```

We can get the value with out the currency symbol using the `autoNumeric` public method `get`.

Comment: can you provide the Fiddle for the same with alert value?
Input String `€650,-`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on your server side, this works.

```
string x = "€650,-";
x = Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9,]", "");
x = x.Split(',')[0];
```

**Output:**

`650`

Answer (score 1):

Now this is possible with plugin default options.

```
new AutoNumeric(".money-val", { unformatOnSubmit: true  });
```

After form submission, it automatically formatted again on mouse hover on input field.

```
unformatOnHover:true
```

Comment: This is now the way to go with the latest version of AutoNumeric. However, if you want to submit the unformatted data, and stay on the same page with the formatted data in the form, then you'd prefer to use the [specialized form functions](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/#form-functions) like `anElement.formSubmitNumericString(callback);`. If you want to reformat all the unformatted values, just use `anElement.formReformat();`.